# Convert scala.List[scala.Long] to List<java.util.Long>

Tags: java, scala

In my Scala code I need to interact with Java libraries.

The method I want to use expects parameter of type  `List<java.util.Long>`, but I have Scala type `Option[List[Long]]`. The problem I faced is that I need manually apply `Predef.long2Long` function to convert from Scala `Long` to `java.util.Long`:

```
val userIds = Option(List(1,2,3,4))
val methodParameter = userIds.map(list => list.map(long2Long).asJava).orNull
```

is there some way to convert this list in more elegant and concise way?

**EDIT:** I can even simplify question: how to convert `Option[scala.Boolean]` to `java.util.Boolean`? Here I need to do same:

```
isUsed.map(isUsedVal => boolean2Boolean(isUsedVal)).orNull,
```

Answer (score 10):

For the `List[Long]`:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val l = List(1L,2L,3L,4L)

l.map(java.lang.Long.valueOf).asJava
// or 
l.map(_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]).asJava
// or
l.map(Long.box).asJava
```

For the `Option[Boolean]`:

```
val mb = Some(true)

mb.map(java.lang.Boolean.valueOf).orNull
// or 
mb.map(_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]).orNull
// or 
mb.map(Boolean.box).orNull
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you use [JavaConverters](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConverters$) ? and do something like that

```
val sl = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]
val jl : java.util.List[Int] = sl.asJava
```

Comment: In this case it will not convert `scala.Int` to `java.util.Int`. It will only replace List container type from `scala.List` to java `List`

Answer (score 2):

It's worth mentioning that `long2Long` and `boolean2Boolean` are implicit, but that doesn't help you much to make this more elegant or clear, I think.  It does allow you to things like:

```
type JB = java.lang.Boolean
isUsed.fold(null : JB)(implicitly)
//Or:
isUsed.map { b => b : JB }.orNull
//Or even:
isUsed.map[JB](identity).orNull
```

But that's not particularly readable, in my opinion.

These sorts of methods are perfect candidates for an [implicit class method](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html).  You can enrich your classes with these methods so that you only have to write the tedious or inelegant code once.  For example, you might consider:

```
object MoreJavaConversions {
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
    implicit class RichListLong(val list: Option[List[Long]]) extends AnyVal {
        def asJava : java.util.List[java.lang.Long] = list.map(_.map(long2Long).asJava).orNull
    }
    implicit class RichOptionBoolean(val bool: Option[Boolean]) extends AnyVal {
        def asJava : java.lang.Boolean = bool.map(boolean2Boolean).orNull
    }
}
```

Which would later allow you to do:

```
import MoreJavaConversions._
val myUsers = Option(List(1l, 2l, 3l))

myUsers.asJava //java.util.List[java.lang.Long]
Option(true).asJava //java.lang.Boolean
```